# Using response body from 1st request in 2nd request in k6

Tags: javascript, k6

I'm sending res1 request, saving res1.body and want to use it as a body for post in res2.
However it doesn't have JSON structure but:

`{\\n  \\\"highlight\\\": {\\n    \\\" (...)`

I tried replacing all unnecessary characters like

`var replacedString = payload.replace(/\n/g, '');`

but after `console.log(replacedString);` I still get contaminated JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Problem was related to using JSON.stringify on data I wanted to use. It caused strange format.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).